# No application configuration file found in FUSLOGVW.exe logs

Tags: .net

I m creating a C# .NET Project in which i m trying to load third party Assemblies which are installed in GAC.

But in some machines I m getting an error stating "Unable to Load assembly of specified version 7.0.351.0".

when i tried to do an assembly redirection it didn't work it still shows the same error.

Note:
7.0.351.0 -The is version with which it is compiled.

12.0.0.0 - Assembly present in the Target machine

Properties of Reference
Specific Version -> False

Aliases -> global

Copy Local -> False

This is my sample application configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" >
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity
                    name="Act.Framework"
                    publicKeyToken="ebf6b2ff4d0a08aa" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.351.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly> 
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Logs of FUSLOGVW shows

"LOG: No application configuration file found."

But I already added the App Config file. Is it not detecting my config file?

How do I make it detect?

Steps I did to add App.Config file:

1. Add New Item through Project wizard and select "Application Configuration file".

Answer (score 6):

Check the path containing the `web.config`. If your `web.config` file is in a directory path that has one or more of folders named with a "#" in the name, Microsoft Fusion will completely ignore the `web.config` for all `assemblyBinding` entries.

Comment: This blew my mind. Brad, you got any cites for that?

Comment: unbelievable! you sir are very right! MS technology sucks big time! So stupid that a # in the path is breaking IIS asp.net app...

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the culture of the assembly in your bindingRedirect:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Act.Framework"
                              publicKeyToken="ebf6b2ff4d0a08aa"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.351.0"
                             newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

You also need to verify that the new version of the assembly is signed with exactly the same private key as the old one.

As far as the the configuration file is concerned verify that it is called `ABC.exe.config` where `ABC` is the name of your executable and that it is in the same folder (if this is a windows application of course, for web applications you need to use `web.config`).